# How to pass an image from one activity to another using Intents in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm a web developer but recently started exploring the Android development world using Xamarin but I'm struggling to find a way to do this task.

My image is located in drawables-hdpi.

In my main activity, I've set a header image on an imageview using this tutorial http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/

Now, I created another activity where when a user clicks on my header image, the second activity comes into action and allows the user to pan and zoom around the image.

I need the second activity to dynamically receive the image from the first activity.

Here's what I've tried but with no success. I'm using the same "load images efficiently" code in the second activity as well, but I don't think that matters anyway.

```
  // set image
  BitmapFactory.Options options = await GetBitmapOptionsOfImage();

  Bitmap bitmapToDisplay = await LoadScaledDownBitmapForDisplayAsync (Resources, options, 400, 400);
  headerImage.SetImageBitmap(bitmapToDisplay);

  headerImage.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ImageScaleActivity));

    headerImage.BuildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap image = headerImage.GetDrawingCache(true);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.PutParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
    intent.PutExtras(extras);

    // TODO: dynamically get image name and send to next activity

    StartActivity(intent);

  };
```

That code isn't working, I'm not getting any errors however when I tap on my header image, nothing shows up in the second activity, so the image is obviously not being sent.

Here's the code in my second activity.

```
  // set image
  BitmapFactory.Options options = await GetBitmapOptionsOfImage();

  Bitmap bitmapToDisplay = await LoadScaledDownBitmapForDisplayAsync (Resources, options, 400, 400);
  //expandedImage.SetImageBitmap(bitmapToDisplay);

  Bundle extras = Intent.Extras;
  Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.GetParcelable("imagebitmap");

  expandedImage.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
```

I just don't think I'm going about this the proper way and I don't see why something like this seems so difficult to do!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image in your drawable then there is no need to send it to the second activity. Just set it drawable in your second activity like this.

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
Drawable  drawable  = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Yes they're in drawables, but the images will be loaded in using a database so if an image for a page is changed in the database (tied to a cms) then your approach won't work.

Comment: If they are in database then send the image url in database using intent

Answer (score -1):

```
You need to put the image in the Intent referring to the Activity 2.
You can use byte array to send the Image.
Byte[] pic; // Contains the Picture. 

In you Main Activity make an intent of Activity2.
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
  myIntent.PutExtra("Picture_from_Activity1",pic);
  this.StartActivity(myIntent);

Now in Activity2 Receive and display the picture.
byte[] recPic = Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("Picture_from_Activity1");

Now convert this Picture to bitmap and display it.
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(recPic,0,recPic.Length);
ImageView iv;
iv.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

:)
```